# Setting a copyright for the future

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I know nothing about copyright but I'm pretty sure this isn't allowed.

I am aware of a website showcasing a portfolio of work. There are images which are themselves the work or images of things that are the work as well as some prose.

However the website marks these as copyright 2023 (2 years in the future as of writing).

Is this allowed? Illegal? Invalid?

My understanding would be that works are copyrighted for something like the life of artist plus 50 years but this also appears like they are trying to buy 2 extra years at the end. Is it protected now? Can I not just steal it?

Basically, what gives?

Comment: Are you sure that's AD and not a different calendar?

Comment: It just says copyright 2023. I think we may assume that it is AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Copyright exists from the moment of creation of the work

Copyright notices and dates are neither required nor meaningful. They are a courtesy to others.

They can also have typos.

Comment: There are procedural advantages to copyright notices under U.S. law that impact the remedies available. But errors in the date don't deny someone those benefits.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks